# Azure - Logging in using Microsoft Office 365 Account

Tags: php, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm creating a system that allows users to login using their Office365 account. I'm following the instructions on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code).

My understanding is that I have to register the app in [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/). Then, get the `Application ID`, and then I can create a link with the proper parameters like this:

```
<!-- DISREGARD THE NEW LINE. IT IS JUST TO SHOW YOU THE PARAMETERS THAT I USED -->
<a href="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
    client_id=xxxxxxxx-1597-46f2-9064-076cee516b3c&
    response_type=id_token&
    redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2Fuser%2Fverify&
    response_mode=form_post&
    scope=openid&
    state=pageTheUserIsOnCurrently&
    nonce=Testing">Sign in Using Microsoft Account</a>
```

Then, it should be redirected to http://localhost/myapp/user/verify (*this is the page that I should process the returned `id_token` using PHP*), which was stated in the `redirect_uri` parameter in the provided link. But after clicking the link and logging in a Microsoft Credentials, I'm getting an error:

> Correlation ID: xxxxxxxx-3292-44b5-b3d8-6aa89a6a65db
>   Timestamp: 2017-10-01 09:40:49Z
>   AADSTS70001: Application 'xxxxxxxx-1597-46f2-9064-076cee516b3c' is not supported for this API version.

Why am I getting such error? What should be done? Did I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

An app that works with the v2.0 endpoint should be registered in new app registration portal: **apps.dev.microsoft.com** . You register the app in Azure Portal , then it is an app works with the Azure AD V1.0 endpoint , that's why the error occurs .

If your requirement is to sign-in using Microsoft Account , you should register the app in apps.dev.microsoft.com and using the v2.0 endpoints . Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare) for more details about the v2.0 endpoint .